# Magento not displaying paths correctly for files

Tags: magento-1.9, paths

My server has just been updated and now on my site the file paths for css, js and everything is wrong: the path weirdly includes the document root, so the path looks like:

> https://www.example.co.uk/var/www/html/www.example.co.uk/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/css/styles.css

First thing I checked was the core table and can confirm the core table looks correct:

[image: the core table]

The secure url and unsecure url are correctly set as:

- https://www.example.co.uk/
- http://www.example.co.uk/

I am lost as to why this is happening. I am thinking it could be a Selinux issue:

> `ls -Z`: Shows, for example `unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 var system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 favicon.ico`

**UPDATE:**
This is a SElinux issue with permissions. I have managed to overcome this for now by setting the SElinux to permissive mode.

I guess I could run:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/magentofoldername/*
```

But, not this is the best thing. I was wondering if someone had a more educated idea of how to best approach this? like how would I correctly set the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before if my base_url doesn't have a `/` at the end.

I've also seen it be an issue if there's an error with the cached data on merged JS/CSS. Try turning on/off merged JS/CSS, see if that helps...

Comment: it's an Selinux issue, as setting it in permissive mode has solved it. Need to figure out correct SElinux now for Magento